Unique identification of poles and zeros of two LTI systems
I have two linear systems in cascade, whose individual orders are known. The input u to the first linear system and the output y at the end of the second linear system are available. The intermediate signal is not known. The transfer function of the complete system is available, whose order is the sum of the order of two individual systems. Now, I would like to identify the transfer functions of the two individual systems. Consider an example where I have a 6th order transfer function (an estimate) and the two linear systems should have TFs of order 3 each. In other words, I have 6 zeros and 6 poles (estimates) available, and I want to assign 3 zeros and poles to one linear system and the remaining 3 to another, such that they match the true TF of the linear systems. What is the easiest way of achieving this? I have tried to assign poles and zeros to individual systems, which is time-consuming, if the order of the TF is higher.

If the intermediate signal isn't available: there is no way you can identify which poles and zeros belong to which of the two systems (if  that's what you are asking).  Any possible allocation of poles and zeros to System 1 or 2 will have the exact same overall transfer function.

Yes, that's my question. Thank you

Sorry, than the answer is no. Can't be done.


Now, I would like to identify the transfer functions of the two individual systems.

Unfortunately this is not possible if the intermediate signal isn't available. There is a large number of possible permutations on how you can allocate 6 poles and zeros to two cascaded system. However for all of these the final overall transfer function will be identical, i.e. they are all indistinguishable if the only things you have are overall input and output.
Small disclaimer: in terms of numerical performance of an actual filter implementation pole zero pairing and section ordering does indeed make a (sometimes significant) difference so technically you could reverse engineer this from the noise in the output signal, but that would require detailed knowledge of the filter topology and also that the numerical noise is indeed the dominant noise source in the output (which is rare).
